# After a command ran in GNU parallel exits, how can I automatically send SIGINT to another command ran by the same instance of GNU parallel?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-parallel, sigint

This is the command I'm running:

```bash
parallel -u ::: 'watch -n 0.1 /home/cringeposter/zfs-mount.sh' 'watch -n 0.1 drill graph.microsoft.com' 'rclone bisync onedrive: /home/cringeposter/zfs/onedrive --verbose --check-access --ignore-checksum' 'rclone bisync onedrive-uni: /home/cringeposter/zfs/onedrive-uni --verbose --check-access --ignore-checksum'
```

The two rclone commands are doing bidirectional syncs on two directories. The `zfs-mount.sh` script is needed because of an [issue with ZFS on Linux where encrypted datasets get randomly unmounted](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/12418#issuecomment-1058334937), while the `drill` call is needed to avoid rclone stopping because it's not able to resolve a domain (this way the IP address is cached by dnsmasq).

Right now I have to manually stop GNU parallel after the bisync completes successfully by pressing CTRL+C in the terminal emulator, but it would be nice if it was done automatically.
The two `watch` processes keep running after the two `rclone` processes exit, is there any way to automatically send them a SIGINT after both `rclone` processes have exited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like (tested):

```
parallel -j0 --halt now,done=2 --lb \
  ::: "ping pi.dk" "ping tange.dk" \
      "traceroute pi.dk" "traceroute tange.dk"
```

(untested):

```
parallel -j0 --halt now,done=2 --lb \
  ::: 'watch -n 0.1 /home/cringeposter/zfs-mount.sh' \
      'watch -n 0.1 drill graph.microsoft.com' \
      'rclone bisync onedrive: /home/cringeposter/zfs/onedrive --verbose --check-access --ignore-checksum' \
      'rclone bisync onedrive-uni: /home/cringeposter/zfs/onedrive-uni --verbose --check-access --ignore-checksum'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `-u` instead of `--lb` though because the latter would generate garbled output, the output of `watch` would partially overwrite the output of `rclone`.